# Laravel return view with file attachment

Tags: php, laravel, http, download

I need to somehow return view with file attachment in it. so file download will start immediately after page loads. I know i can do it with javascript (make ajax request for that file when page loads). But i was wondering maybe there is more proper way of achieving this in Laravel, maybe like

```
return view('view')->withAttachment($myFile);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to do it all in one go. You can't have a response which sends both a HTML document (for the browser to read) *and* a file for download. They are two separate items, which have a different structure, different response headers etc. etc.

N.B. This is true of any HTTP request, it's not specific to Laravel or PHP.